# Multivariate Granger's causality

Tags: r, linear-regression, multivariate-testing, causality

I'm having issues doing a multivariate Granger's causal test. I'll like to check if conditioning a third variable affects the results of a causal test.
Here's one sample for a single dependent and independent variable based on an earlier question I asked and was answered by @Alex

[Granger's causality test by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984606/column-wise-grangers-causal-tests-in-r)

```
library(lmtest)
M1<- matrix( c(2,3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1,1, 5, 7), nrow=5, ncol=2)
M2<- matrix( c(7,3, 6, 9, 1, 2, 1,2, 8, 1), nrow=5, ncol=2)  
M3<- matrix( c(1, 3, 1,5, 7,3, 1, 3, 3, 4), nrow=5, ncol=2)
```

For example, the equation for a conditioned linear regression will be

```
formula = y ~ w + x * z
```

How do I carry out this test as a function of a third or fourth variable please?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The solution for *stationary variables* are well-established: See [`FIAR` (v 0.3) package](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/FIAR/).

[This is the paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v044i13/v44i13.pdf) related with the package that includes concrete example of multivariate Granger causality (in the case of all of the variables are stationary).
Page 12: Theory, Page 15: Practice.

**2.** In case of *mixed (stationary, nonstationary) variables*, make all the variables stationary first (via differencing etc.). Do not handle stationary ones (they are already stationary). Now again, you finish by the above procedure (in case I).

**3.** In case of *"non-cointegrated nonstationary" variables*, then there is no need for VECM. Run VAR with the stationary variables (by making them stationary first, of course). Apply `FIAR::condGranger` etc.

**4.** In case of *"cointegrated nonstationary" variables*, the answer is really really very long: 
Johansen Procedure (detect rank via `urca::cajo`)
Apply `vec2var` to convert VECM to VAR (since `FIAR` is based on VAR).
[John Hunter's latest book](http://www.palgrave.com/gp/book/9780230243309) nicely summarizes what can happen and what can be done in this last case.

You may wanna read [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271729580_Causfinder_An_R_package_for_Systemwise_Analysis_of_Conditional_and_Partial_Granger_Causalities) as well.

*To my knowledge:*  Conditional/partial Granger causality supersides the GC via "Block exogeneity Wald test over VAR".