# Allowing for aliased coefficients when running `grangertest()` in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, regression

I'm currently trying to run a granger causality analysis in R/R Studio. I am receiving errors about aliased coefficients when using the function `grangertest()`. From my understanding, this occurs because there is perfect multicolinearity between the variables.

Due to having a very large number of pairwise comparisons (e.g. 200+), I would like to simply run the granger with the aliased coefficients as per normal rather than returning an error. According to one answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/what-are-aliased-coefficients), the solution is or was to add set `singular.ok=TRUE`, but either I am doing it incorrectly the answer s out of date. I've tried checking the documentation, but have come up empty. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(lmtest)
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(0,3,6,9)
grangertest(x,y,1) # I want this to run successfully even if there are aliased coefficients. 
grangertest(x,y,1, singular.ok=TRUE) # this also doesn't work 

"Error in waldtest.lm(fm, 2, ...) : 
  there are aliased coefficients in the model"
```

Additionally is there a way to flag `x` and `y` are actually aliased variables? There seem to be some answers like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/what-are-aliased-coefficients) but I'm having issues getting it working properly.

```
alias((x~ y))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation and emailing the creator of the grangertest package, they sent me this solution. The solution should run on aliased variables when granger test does not. When the variables are not aliased, the solution should give the same values as the normal granger test.

```
library(lmtest)
library(dynlm)
 
# Some data that is multicolinear
x <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
y <- c(0,3,6,9,12)

# Some data that is not multicolinear
# x <- c(0,125,200,230,777)
# y <- c(0,3,6,9,200)

# Convert to time series (this is an important step)
x=ts(x)
y=ts(y)

# This will run even when the data is multicolinear (but also when it is not)
# and is functionally the same as running the granger test (which by default uses the waldtest

m1 = dynlm(x ~ L(x, 1:1) + L(y, 1:1))
m2 = dynlm(x ~ L(x, 1:1))
result <-anova(m1, m2, test="F")
 
# This will fail if the data is multicolinear or aliased but should give the same results as the anova otherwise (F value and P value etc)
#grangertest(y,x,1)
```