# Three Dimensional Panel Data: Granger Causality Test in R

Tags: r, regression, panel, plm, causality

I have data which is structured the following:
[image]

As you can see, I have "multi-dimensional panel data", i.e. I do not only have years and countries, but also industries as a third "index". I did a panel regression analysis with the `fixest` package to investigate if PE industry (which is a dummy variable) has an impact on employment growth. Moreover, I included several fixed effects in the regression analysis (in this case country-year, industry-year and country-industry).

What I want to do now, is test for granger causality with the `pgrangertest` formula from the `plm` package. However, for the panel analysis I did not use the `plm` package since I was not able to incorporate three indexes (i.e., year, country, industry) and I was not able to incorporate the three fixed interaction effects (i.e., country-year, industry-year and country-industry). This was much easier with the `fixest` package and the `feols` formula. This is the formula I used for the regression: `feols(Employment Growth ~ PE Industry | Country^Year+Industry^Year+Country^Industry, data = Example)`

However, the fixest package does not provide a (panel) Granger causality test formula. Hence, I assume I need to switch to the `plm` package, but I have no idea how to transfer my formula for the regression to the `plm` package and hence, how to compute the causality test.

Any ideas - potentially with code examples?

Answer (score 1):

The panel Granger non-causality test by Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012) [1], implemented in `pgrangertest` of package `plm`, is really just about two variables (in their original values) in two dimension (observational unit (in your case country) and time period (in your case year)). So, country and year will work. For industry and year you would need some kind of aggregation over industry (e.g., mean per year) if that makes sense for the question at hand. Country, industry, and year at the same time is not possible.

Also, the test does not pick up a user-specified regression model.

`pgrangertest` uses a formula object to specify the test but it is really just `variable_A ~ variable_B`.

Example from the help page of the function `?pgrangertest`:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
pgrangertest(inv ~ value, data = Grunfeld)
#> 
#>  Panel Granger (Non-)Causality Test (Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012))
#> 
#> data:  inv ~ value
#> Ztilde = 3.2896, p-value = 0.001003
#> alternative hypothesis: Granger causality for at least one individual
```

[1] Dumitrescu E, Hurlin C (2012). “Testing for Granger non-causality in heterogeneous panels.” Economic Modelling, 29(4), 1450 - 1460. ISSN 0264-9993, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999312000491

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I understand that - and that is basically what I want BUT with three "identifier" which is unusual for panel data. Usually you have a time and id dimension (e.g. year and countries), but I also have the industry dimension. hence, when using the pgrangertest formula it says I have duplicates in my identifiers (since e.g. year-country combination is not unique but year-country-industry observations are). Any help here?

Comment: The test is only defined along two dimensions and I have just edited my answer to include that. So, country and year will work. For industry and year you would need some kind of aggregation over industry (e.g., mean per year) if that makes sense for the question at hand. Country, industry, and year at the same time is not possible.